# Nagios NDOUtils installation - can't load mysql.so error

Tags: mysql, linux, installation, nagios

Hi I m very new to Linux & mysql...while I m installing ndoutils for nagios ,I have to execute this command from Db folder---

```
./installdb -u root -p root -h localhost -d nagios
```

while executing this command m getting this error-

> install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load
>   '/usr/lib/perl5/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so' for module DBD::mysql:
>   libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory at /usr/lib/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 200.  at (eval 7) line
>   3 Compilation failed in require at (eval 7) line 3. Perhaps a required
>   shared library or dll isn't installed where expected  at ./installdb
>   line 41

What should I do to remove this error? Help me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!  If you post error messages, **PLEASE** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message. And one `?` is quite enough to get our attention - no need to go overboard here.....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install DRD::mysql for perl.

http://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql